# Why is the DLL not copied to output directory? C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

I set up a c++ project to use a DLL in visual studio. The library had .h .lib and .dll files. The program compiles and runs, and successfully uses the library. The DLL was put in the root directory of the **source**, not the output directory. When I build, I expected the DLL to be copied form the source to the output directory, but it's not. All I see in the output directory is 3 files of type, application, incremental linker file, and program debug database.

Maybe I'm wrong but I thought that the DLL needed to be in the same folder as the executable in the output directory. So what's going on?

Comment: Try starting the program outside of VS, then it searches in the same directory. One of the many strange things of VS.

Comment: @deviantfan if i start it outside of VS by clicking on the app in the output directory it can't find the dll ; /

Comment: Default output directory is the *solution* directory, not the project build directory.  Which ensures all projects generate their output to the same directory and your solution will work.  It is a setting that can be changed, General page.

Comment: @Ragdoll Yes, exactly. Because VS didn´t put it in the same dir.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes the output directory is in the solution directory but i dont see how that has anything to do with what were talking about

Comment: Didn't you change environment PATH variables so to point to DLL's source directory?

Comment: @SergeRogatch I dont think so but how would I check this?

Comment: @Ragdoll, right click on your executable project, click menu item "Properties", then go to Debugging -> Environment . Check the environment variables set there.

Comment: @SergeRogatch config prop > debugging > environment, empty line

Comment: @SergeRogatch OHH but, the working directory is set to the project directory, that must be it right?

Comment: @Ragdoll, is it the same what you call the "source" directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is something I had difficulty finding as well, but VS does not copy the .dll's for you. You have to tell it to by creating a Post-Build event. Check out the link on XCOPY:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/240268

I needed to copy some dll's to my target directory (the build directory) so used the following in a Post-Build event in my project settings:

```
xcopy $(ProjectDir)openal32.dll $(TargetDir) /Y /D
```

Just replace "openal32.dll" with whatever dll you need to copy and make a new build event for each dll you need copied to the target (build) directory.

/Y suppresses prompting to confirm overwrite 
/D instructs the compiler to only copy if it's a newer version of the dll on this build.

Answer (score 1):

> When I build, I expected the DLL to be copied form the source to the
>   output directory, but it's not.
>
> Maybe I'm wrong but I thought that the DLL needed to be in the same
>   folder as the executable in the output directory. So what's going on?

First, DLL's are not part of the build process, that's one reason why Visual Studio doesn't do anything with your DLL.

Having said that, another reason why Visual Studio shouldn't automatically copy over the DLL to your executable directory is that Visual Studio doesn't and cannot assume this is where you want your DLL placed.

It can't assume this because you may want your DLL to be placed in one of the directories that will be found by the Windows OS when it is time to load the DLL.  See this link:

[Dynamic Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

What if you are testing your app to see if it will load the DLL correctly if it is placed in a certain directory on your PATH?  How will you do that if Visual Studio were to always copy the DLL to your executable directory?

Another scenario:  What if your program uses `LoadLibrary` and wants to test if the program behaves correctly if the DLL is *not* found?

As the other answer suggested, that's why you have to make the concerted effort of telling Visual Studio what to do in the post build event.  Also, even after applying the post build event, Visual Studio still knows absolutely nothing about your DLL -- all it sees is a `copy` or `xcopy` command.