# Azure Web App Referencing DLL in Windows Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

We are looking to get out of a Virtual Machine and convert a C# MVC website into an Azure Web App. The only hurdle, is that our web application references a C++ project that uses a DLL that has to be stored in the OS's Windows directory. Anyone know how to get around this or any other options?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [post-build action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp#to-copy-the-dll-in-a-post-build-event) in your project, and add the commands to copy the offending DLL. The post-build action are written as a batch script.

The output directory can be referenced as `$(OutDir)`. The project directory is available as `$(ProjDir)`. Try to use relative paths where applicable, so that you can copy or move your project folder without breaking the post-build action.

You needed to copy some dlls to target directory (the build directory) so used the following in a [Post-Build event in my project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222152/why-is-the-dll-not-copied-to-output-directory-c-visual-studio):

```
xcopy $(ProjectDir)openal32.dll $(TargetDir) /Y /D
```

Here are some commonly used switches with xcopy:

```
/I - treat as a directory if copying multiple files
/Q - Do not display the files being copied.
/S - Copy subdirectories unless empty.
/E - Copy empty subdirectories.
/Y - Do not prompt for overwrite of existing files.
/R - Overwrite read only files.
```

Comment: Thanks... will give that a try.